# What are the reasons of using several HDFS Name Nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

The official HDFS doc sayd the following:

> The existence of a single NameNode in a cluster greatly simplifies the architecture of the system.

And I am interested in what are the reasons of using several Name Nodes?
Are there any?

Answer (score 0):

What do you do when a Namenode fails? You loose all your data, regardless of anything that exists on the Datanodes.

You can't perform a cluster upgrade with no downtime with only a single NameNode

If you had a Namenode failure without a standby, you'd better be sure you're taking periodic namenode backups.

Note: prior to Hadoop 3, there was a limitation to 2 Namenodes